# Why does let y = 1 + y compile, and what does it mean?

Tags: haskell

In GHCi `let y = y + 1` compiles fine, but when I try to evaluate y I got `*** Exception: <<loop>>`

Why is there no compile error and what does it mean `<<loop>>`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Haskell `let`, `where` and top-level bindings are **recursive by default**, even if they're not for a function. So `let y = y + 1` defines an infinite loop of adding `1` to a number. GHC represents loops like this with the `<<loop>>` exception—if it can catch them, of course!

This is usable for lazy operations, because it allows us to easily define things like infinite lists (`let xs = 0:xs`), which are well-defined and actually useful for normal code. However, it can't work for strict operations like `+` (for most numeric types) because they require evaluating the whole (infinite) thing right away.

Comment: I've created a file with two lines
y :: Int
y = 1 + y

and loaded in into GHCi. No compiler errors. So look like it is not only for let binding by for any definition.

Thank you for your answer

Comment: @Aler: Right, I should clarify that: `let`, `where` and top level bindings are all recursive. The only exception you are likely to encounter is names defined with `<-` in do-notation, largely because that has more meaning than just defining a variable.

Comment: I believe <<loop>> isn't really about GHC catching anything, but rather it is a runtime error caused by trying to enter a blackhole.

Comment: @PhilipJF: Well, it's more like the RTS catching it at runtime. After all, how do you know you're in a black hole? You can't in general, so it's just a heuristic of some sort. I'm not sure exactly what it is though.

Comment: Compare: `int get_value_of_y() { return get_value_of_y() + 1; }` in imperative languages

Comment: @TikhonJelvis, in GHC a "black hole" is a very specific thing: it's a thunk that's been marked as having been entered, but that has not yet been completely evaluated. In the single-threaded RTS, attempting to enter a black hole is what produces a `<<<loop>>>` exception. No other kind of infinite loop does so. In the multi-threaded RTS, black holes turn into "grey holes". A thread trying to evaluate a grey hole waits (possibly forever) for some other thread to finish evaluating it.

Comment: @TikhonJelvis there is no heuristic: you can figure it out from the CB-need strategy: do you have to evaluate a thunk before you can compute the WHNF of that thunk?  If so, you will end up in <<loop>> or its multi-threaded equivalent, if not, you won't.  You might not be able to decide that statically, but that doesn't matter to the question at hand.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add a minimal example of where this might actually be useful.

```
data Peano = Z | S Peano

instance Num Peano where
    p + Z     = p
    p + (S q) = S (p + q)
    fromInteger 1 = S Z

instance Eq Peano where
    Z     == Z     = True
    Z     == _     = False
    _     == Z     = False
    (S p) == (S q) = p == q

instance Ord Peano where
    Z     `compare` Z     = EQ
    Z     `compare` _     = LT
    _     `compare` Z     = GT
    (S p) `compare` (S q) = p `compare` q

y :: Peano
y = y + 1

main :: IO ()
main = print $ 1 < y
```

In this case, `y` is infinity, up to isomorphism.  (Though, my `fromInteger` is clearly a poor implementation, so changing either literal `1` to something else without fixing `fromInteger` will fail.)

Note that this only works because the `(+)` I've defined is lazy in it's first argument and the `compare` I've defined is also sufficiently lazy.