# Why doesn't year=year+1 fail with stack overflow?

Tags: haskell, ghc, tail-recursion

year.hs:

```
year = year + 1

main = print year
```

This is not a tail recursive call:

```
year = year + 1
year = (year + 1) + 1
year = ((year + 1) + 1) + 1
...
```

However `runhaskell year.hs` does not output anything, which indicates that it run into infinite loop.

Does Haskell compiler make optimizations even for non tail recursive calls?

Comment: Watch your memory usage.  It depends on the optimizations, but that's one thing that can happen.

Comment: What is the supposed output?

Comment: I'd assume the result of this is undefined.

Comment: @Comm The supposed output is `Exception: stack overflow`

Answer (score 19):

Because of laziness (plus the monomorphism restriction<sup>†</sup>).  Basically when you say

```
year = year + 1
```

and then evaluate `year`, Haskell saves space for the result, and then when it sees `year` it tries to re-use the same result.  So when `year + 1` tries to evaluate `year`, the code for `year` doesn't actually get entered.

In GHC, to implement multi-threading<sup>‡</sup>, what it actually does is block the current thread when it tries to obtain the value of a variable that's already being evaluated.  Then when the evaluation finishes, it resumes execution of the blocked thread.  In this case, the thread is being blocked on an evaluation it itself is doing, which is why you get a deadlock.

If you instead say

```
year () = year () + 1
```

then running `year ()` does give a stack overflow for me.

---

<sup>†</sup> The monomorphism restriction comes into play because if you add a type signature

```
year :: Num a => a
year = year + 1
```

the compiler is perfectly free to treat the `Num a` dictionary like the `()` parameter, yielding a stack overflow.  In this case that's not really a problem, but not caching intermediate results is a big problem in real computations.  In this case, it looks like GHC is actually putting the recursion *inside* the abstraction over the dictionary, producing code more like

```
year () = let y = y + 1 in y
```

which also doesn't produce a stack overflow.

---

<sup>‡</sup> Compiling the code (with GHC) in single-threaded mode yields

```
<<loop>>
```

which means GHC detected the infinite loop and decided to complain about it.

Comment: For clarification: The type of ``year`` defaults to ``Int``, or am I mistaken?

Comment: @ThreeFx that sounds reasonable, but I can't check now.  It doesn't matter, though, because you can give `year` any monomorphic type signature (e.g., `year :: Int`, `year :: Integer`, `year :: Float`, etc.) (as long as the type has a `Num` instance) without changing the behavior (as long as `+` on that type is strict)

Comment: @ThreeFx You can change what type whole-number and decimal number literals default to, but the default default is (Integer, Double).

Comment: Just added `year :: Num a => a` and got the same result. Still no stack overflow

Comment: @orionll, just tried it and you are correct.  It looks like GHC *does* optimize this case (putting the recursion inside the dictionary abstraction) so you get the lazy behavior even with a polymorphic type signature.  I'll edit my answer when I get a chance.

Comment: The default is `Integer`, unless you've changed it.

Comment: cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27557380/why-does-let-y-1-y-compile-and-what-does-it-mean/27557396#comment43544793_27557396